# Django: Automatically input currently logged in user as a value in a form

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

I am trying to show logged in users a form where they can input `name` and `sensitivity`, however this needs to be associated with the logged in user (currently attempting this with the foreign key and init). This is my approach:

Views:

```
@login_required
def restricted(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TrackForm(request.user, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)

            return index(request)
        else:
            print form.errors
    else:
        form = TrackForm()

    return render_to_response('tracker/restricted.html', {'form': form}, context)
```

Forms:

```
class TrackForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(help_text="Please enter a name")
    sensitivity = forms.IntegerField(help_text="Sensitivity: 1=Low Sensitivity, 2=Standard Sensitivity, 3=Highly Sensitive", initial=0)

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = user
        super(TrackForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = ToTrack
        fields = ('name','sensitivity')
```

Models:

```
class ToTrack(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    sensitivity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

I currently get the error message:

```
TypeError at /tracker/restricted/
__init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Answer (score 0):

change `views.py` like this(I comment changed line):

```
@login_required
def restricted(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TrackForm(request.POST, user=request.user) #this line change
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)

            return index(request)
        else:
            print form.errors
    else:
        form = TrackForm(user=request.user) #this line change

    return render_to_response('tracker/restricted.html', {'form': form}, context)
```

And change `form` like this:

```
class TrackForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(help_text="Please enter a name")
    sensitivity = forms.IntegerField(help_text="Sensitivity: 1=Low Sensitivity, 2=Standard Sensitivity, 3=Highly Sensitive", initial=0)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        if user:
            self.user = user
        super(TrackForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = ToTrack
        fields = ('name','sensitivity')
```

Comment: Thanks Hasan, I think I follow the logic here :D I'm now getting the error: TypeError at /tracker/restricted/
__init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'user'